# Can we reverse this string in C?

Tags: c, string, format

It is very simple I hope. These are 20 hex values separated by a back-slash `\` and C compiler indeed making them a string of 33 characters because `\NUMBER` is single value `\NUMBER+ALPHA` = 2 bytes as well as `\ALPHA+NUMBER` 2 bytes.

```
char str[] =
"\b3\bc\77\7\de\ed\44\93\75\ce\c0\9\19\59\c8\f\be\c6\30\6";
//when saved is 33 bytes
```

My question is after it has been saved to 33 bytes on disk, can we (after reading 33 bytes) remake the same presentation that we have in C? So the program prints `"\b3\bc\77\7\de\ed\44\93\75\ce\c0\9\19\59\c8\f\be\c6\30\6"`, any problem solvers here?

```
"\b3\bc\77\7\de\ed\44\93\75\ce\c0\9\19\59\c8\f\be\c6\30\6";
//when read back program should output this ^
```

Comment: Sure - why not ? What specific problem is stopping you from doing this ?

Comment: They are not saved as hex value as you would expect it to. That's one thing for sure.

Comment: Why do you believe that this is a valid string literal, or that it will give you what you want?

Comment: @Paul R, Arpit, Ignacio Vaquez-Abrams
Actually - regardless of what string is, when saved it is saved in 33 bytes, assume that it is taken from the output of \\%x of 20 values. Now once read back 33 bytes I want to generate same representation which apparently is 20 places thanks.

Comment: `str` isn't 20 hex values separated by backslashes.

Comment: @Jasonz: Your string will generate warning (at least from gcc). The `char[]` is 33 bytes including 1 byte for NUL: `08 33 08 63 3f 07 64 65 1b 64 24 39 33 3d 63 65 63 30 39 01 39 05 39 63 38 0c 08 65 63 36 18 06 00`, and a number of them are not printable characters.

Comment: I'm confused. What does the \d escape sequence represent?

Comment: Dear @nhahtdh, exactly it will produce the sequence you mentioned when written to disk. Now question is when it is read back can we produce 
>  "\b3\bc\77\7\de\ed\44\93\75\ce\c0\9\19\59\c8\f\be\c6\30\6";
out of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string literal you have:

```
"\b3\bc\77\7\de\ed\44\93\75\ce\c0\9\19\59\c8\f\be\c6\30\6"
```

will produce undefined behavior according to [C89](http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt) (not sure if the source for C89 can be trusted, but my point below still holds) and implementation-defined behavior according to [C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) standard. In particular, `\d`, `\e`, `\9`, `\c` are escape sequences not defined in the standard. `gcc` will not complain about `\e`, since it is a GNU extension, which represent ESC.

Since there are implementation-defined behavior, it is necessary for us to know what compiler you are using as the result may vary.

Another thing is that, you didn't show *clearly* that you are aware of the content of the string after compilation. (A clearer way to show would be to include a hex dump of what the string looks like in memory, and show how you are aware of the escape sequences).

This is how the *looks-like-hex* string is recognized by the compiler:

```
String: \b  3 \b  c \77 \7 \d  e \e  d \44 \9  3 \75 \c  e \c 0  \9 \1  9 \5  9 \c  8 \f \b  e \c  6 \20 \6
Char:   \b  3 \b  c \77 \7  d  e \e  d \44 \9  3 \75  c  e  c 0   9 \1  9 \5  9  c  8 \f \b  e  c  6 \20 \6
Hex:    08 33 08 63  3f 07 64 65 1b 64  24 39 33  3d 63 65 63 30 39 01 39 05 39 63 38 0c 08 65 63 36  18 06 00
```

Enough beating around the bush. Assuming that you are using `gcc` to compile the code (warnings ignored). When the code is run, the whole `char[]` is written to file using `fwrite`. I also assume only lower case characters are used in the source code.

You should map all possible escape sequences `\xy` that looks like 2-digit hex number to sequences of 1 or 2 bytes. There are not that many of them, and you can write a program to simulate the behavior of the compiler:

- If `x` is any of `a`, `b`, `f` (other escape sequences like `\n` are not hex digit) and `e` (due to GNU extension). It is mapped to special character.
- (If you use uppercase character in source code, do note that `\E` maps to ESC)
- If `xy` forms a valid octal sequence. It is mapped to character with corresponding value.
- If `x` forms a valid octal sequence. It is mapped to character with corresponding value.
- Otherwise, `x` stays the same.
- If `y` is not consumed, `y` stays the same.

Note that it is possible for the actual `char` to come from 2 different ways. For example, `\f` and `\14` will map to the same `char`. In such case, it might not be possible to get back the string in the source. The most you can do is guess what the string in the source can be.

Use your string as an example, at the beginning, `08` and `33` can come from `\b3`, but it can also come from `\10\63`.

Using the map produce, there are cases where the mapping is clear: hex larger than `3f` cannot come from octal escape sequence, and must come from direct interpretation of the character in the original string. From this, you know that if `e` is encountered, it must be the 2nd character in a looks-like-hex sequence.

You can use the map as a guide, and the simulation as a method to check whether the map will produce back the ASCII code. Without knowing anything about the string declared in the source code, the most you can derive is a list of candidates for the original (broken) string in the source code. You can reduce the size of the list of candidates if you at least know the length of the string in the source code.

Comment: I think the OP just misunderstood how to write hex escapes...

Comment: @JimGarrison: Not sure what the OP wants, since it is a very weird question in the first place. Have you take a look at the comments in the question?

Comment: response highly appreciated dear @nhahtdh